# DOCTYPE Issue with asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Page keeps telling me that my

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

is missing, but it is in my aspx file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Title="" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Index" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

However, it seems that the asp markup on Line 1 is causing this issue. If I take it out of the page it runs fine, but my page then cannot access my server side code from javascript. Previously I was using a MasterPage setup and this code worked fine, but I am no longer doing that and wanted to use my index.aspx page and index.aspx.cs file exclusively to run my site.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: where and what is say that this is missing ? do you see this if you open the source on browser ?

Comment: The exact message is:

HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>". Line 1

Comment: Are the `html`, `head` and `body` tags all there too? What happens if you remove `debug`? Does `Inherits` match the code-behind class name?

Comment: all true and do exist yes. I removed debug and it's the same outcome. this one has me stumped